# How to convert XML to Array in XQuery?

Tags: xpath, xquery

Consider I have the following data:

```
let $fruits := <fruits>
    <fruit id="apple" />
    <fruit id="orange" />
</fruits>
```

how can I use the data in variable `$fruits` and parse it to become `$fruits2 := ('apple', 'orange')`?

I have  `fn:tokenize` function in my mind but this only work with string.
Thanks in advance for any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
let $fruits2 := $fruits/fruit/@id/data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, there are no arrays in XQuery 1.0 and 3.0 only sequences. However, it is looking very likely at the moment that XQuery 3.1 will include an array type.